# Invariance of volume form under coordinate transformations

Tags: differential-geometry, covariance

For my topology class I have to show the following:

> Let $g = g_{ij} \; dx^i \otimes dx^j$ be a metric on a differentiable manifold. Show that the volume form $dV = \sqrt{\det g} \; dx^1 \land ... \land dx^n$ is invariant under coordinate transformations.

Now, I am not quite sure what I have to do here. If $x = (x^1, ..., x^n) $ is a set of coordinates and $\tilde{x} = (\tilde{x}^1, ..., \tilde{x}^n)$ is another set of coordinates, then do I have to show that

$$d\tilde{V}( \tilde{x} ) \enspace = \enspace dV(x) \quad ?$$

But how do I know how $d\tilde{V}(\tilde{x})$ looks like? Does anyone have a hint for me?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Well, I guess since differential geometry is essential for e.g. general relativity I thought it would be fruitful to post this question here. Frankly though, I posted it in mathematics too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of volume density transformation under infinitesimal diffeomorphisms using Levi-civita/ determinant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/591130/132418)

Comment: You have to show that the *general formula* for the component of the volume element, that is, the prescription "take the square root of the determinant of the metric's components" is a prescription valid in all coordinates.

Comment: To be honest I don't like how they worded the problem in your class, though. Any tensor or form, per se, is coordinate invariant, since it's the same object no matter which coordinates we choose – *if* we choose any. What may be invariant are particular expressions for the tensor components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using basic coordinate transformation rules for tensors ($g_{ij}$ and $dx^i$), as well as antisymmetric properties of the wedge product, show that the wedge product
$dx^1\wedge\dots dx^n$ transforms as follows under coordinate transformations:

$$
dx^1\wedge\dots dx^n=\frac{\partial(x)}{\partial(\tilde{x})}\,d\tilde{x}^1\wedge\dots d\tilde{x}^n
$$

Where $\frac{\partial(x)}{\partial(\tilde{x})}$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix. Then, again using coordinate transformations, show that

$$
\mbox{det}\left[\tilde{g}\right]=\left(\frac{\partial(x)}{\partial(\tilde{x})}\right)^2\,\mbox{det}\left[g\right]
$$

Conclude that, under coordinate transformations:

$$
dx^1\wedge\dots dx^n=\sqrt{\frac{\mbox{det}\left[\tilde{g}\right]}{\mbox{det}\left[g\right]}}\frac{\partial(x)}{\partial(\tilde{x})}\,d\tilde{x}^1\wedge\dots d\tilde{x}^n
$$

Finally conclude that:

$$
\sqrt{\mbox{det}\left[g\right]}\cdot dx^1\wedge\dots dx^n = 
\sqrt{\mbox{det}\left[\tilde{g}\right]}\cdot d\tilde{x}^1\wedge\dots d\tilde{x}^n 
$$

i.e. the form of this quantity does not change as you change coordinates.

Finally, finally, note that any manifold is locally a Cartesian space, and there, in Cartesian coordinates $\mbox{det}\left[g\right]=1$ and $dx^1\wedge \dots dx^n=d^nV$, the standard volume form. From this conclude that $d^n V=\sqrt{\mbox{det}\left[g\right]}dx^1\wedge \dots dx^n$ is the correct volume form in any coordinate system and at all points on the manifold

---

Adding more specifics. I would suggest [https://www.amazon.com/Tensors-Differential-Variational-Principles-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00A735HK8#reader_B00A735HK8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A735HK8). It deals with all that you want in a rigorous and hands-on-way.

To compute the determinant of the metric tensor you need a way of expressing this determinant using tensors. At this point on usually reaches for Levi-Civita, but the problem with that is that Levi-Civita is not a tensor (it is a relative tensor, in the language of Lovelock and Rund). Fortunately, there is something called generalized Kroenecker delta [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Definitions_of_the_generalized_Kronecker_delta], which is a tensor (to prove this note that generalized Kroenecker delta can be written as products of usual Kronecker delta's $\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}$, so it is sufficient to prove that latter is a tensor).

Ok, with that:

$$
\det\left[\tilde{g}\right]=\tilde{\delta}^{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_n}_{1\dots n}\tilde{g}_{1\alpha_1}\dots\tilde{g}_{n\alpha_n}
$$

To check that, note that $\tilde{\delta}^{1\dots n}_{1\dots n}=1$ and then picks up a factor of -1 on every exchange of $\alpha$-s. Now you can apply change of coordinates to the RHS, since there you only have tensors:

$$
\begin{align}
\det\left[\tilde{g}\right]=\frac{\partial x^{\mu_1}}{\partial \tilde{x}^1}\dots\frac{\partial x^{\mu_n}}{\partial \tilde{x}^n}\cdot
\delta^{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_n}_{\mu_1 \dots \mu_n} \cdot 
\frac{\partial x^{\sigma_1}}{\partial \tilde{x}^1}\dots \frac{\partial x^{\sigma_n}}{\partial \tilde{x}^n}
\cdot g_{\sigma_1\alpha_1}\dots g_{\sigma_n\alpha_n}
\end{align}
$$

Firstly deal with sum over $\mu$-s. Let's look at just two terms, for example:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x^{\mu_1}}{\partial \tilde{x}^1}\dots\frac{\partial x^{\mu_n}}{\partial \tilde{x}^n}\cdot
\delta^{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_n}_{\mu_1 \dots \mu_n} =& \frac{\partial x^{1}}{\partial \tilde{x}^1}\frac{\partial x^{2}}{\partial \tilde{x}^2}\dots\frac{\partial x^{n}}{\partial \tilde{x}^n}\cdot
\delta^{\alpha_1 \dots\alpha_n}_{1, 2\dots n} +
\frac{\partial x^{2}}{\partial \tilde{x}^1}\frac{\partial x^{1}}{\partial \tilde{x}^2}\dots\frac{\partial x^{n}}{\partial \tilde{x}^n}\cdot
\delta^{\alpha_1 \dots\alpha_n}_{2, 1\dots n}+\dots\\
=& \frac{\partial x^{1}}{\partial \tilde{x}^1}\frac{\partial x^{2}}{\partial \tilde{x}^2}\dots\frac{\partial x^{n}}{\partial \tilde{x}^n}\cdot
\delta^{\alpha_1 \dots\alpha_n}_{1, 2\dots n} -
\frac{\partial x^{2}}{\partial \tilde{x}^1}\frac{\partial x^{1}}{\partial \tilde{x}^2}\dots\frac{\partial x^{n}}{\partial \tilde{x}^n}\cdot
\delta^{\alpha_1 \dots\alpha_n}_{1, 2\dots n}+\dots
\end{align}
$$

Note the swap of indices on the least delta. In this way we can show that the sum over $\mu$-s consist of a product $\delta^{\alpha_1 \dots\alpha_n}_{1, 2\dots n}$ and a completely anti-symmetrized product of partial derivatives - a Jacobian determinant:

$$
\begin{align}
\det\left[\tilde{g}\right]=\frac{\partial\left(x\right)}{\partial\left(\tilde{x}\right)}\cdot
\delta^{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_n}_{1 \dots n} \cdot 
\frac{\partial x^{\sigma_1}}{\partial \tilde{x}^1}\dots \frac{\partial x^{\sigma_n}}{\partial \tilde{x}^n}
\cdot g_{\sigma_1\alpha_1}\dots g_{\sigma_n\alpha_n}
\end{align}
$$

Next consider:

$$
w_{\sigma_1\dots\sigma_n}=\delta^{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_n}_{1 \dots n}  g_{\sigma_1\alpha_1}\dots g_{\sigma_n\alpha_n}
$$

And note that:

$$
w_{1\dots n}=det\left[g\right]
$$

and any exchange of $\sigma$ indices simply adds a factor of -1 to $w_{\sigma_1\dots\sigma_n}$. We can therefore repeat the trick above to get

$$
\begin{align}
\det\left[\tilde{g}\right]=&\frac{\partial\left(x\right)}{\partial\left(\tilde{x}\right)}\cdot
w_{1\dots n} \cdot 
\frac{\partial\left(x\right)}{\partial\left(\tilde{x}\right)}\\
=&\left(\frac{\partial\left(x\right)}{\partial\left(\tilde{x}\right)}\right)^2\cdot\det\left[g\right]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: For the det.:

$$g = g_{ij} d\tilde{x}^i \otimes d\tilde{x}^j = g_{ij} \frac{\partial d\tilde{x}^i}{\partial dx^k}\frac{\partial d\tilde{x}^j}{\partial dx^{\ell}} dx^k \otimes dx^{\ell}$$

The Jacobian Matrix is $J_{ij} = \frac{\partial d\tilde{x}^i}{\partial dx^j}$ and thus

$$ g = g_{ij} J_{ik} J_{j\ell} \; dx^k \otimes dx^{\ell}  = (J^T g J)_{k\ell} \; dx^k \otimes dx^{\ell} $$

But how do I calculate the det.? Is is just $\det g(\tilde{x}) = (\det J)^2 \det g (x)$? How do I handle the tensor product mathematically rigorous when calculating the det.? Is my way correct so far?

Comment: @Octavius. Firstly $\partial d x^k$ makes no sense. Either $\partial$ or $d$, not both. Secondly don't denote Jacobian matrix with downstairs indices, this will mess up your equations, should be $J^i_j$. Thirdly, use $\mathbf{g}$to denote a non-scalar value, in most texts I have seen, $g$ stands for the *determinant* of the metric tensor. I will try to deal with the bigger question in the main post

Comment: Certainly, you are perfectly right to object $\partial dx^k$. This was just some kind of typo that I carelessly committed. However, thank you for your effort so far.

Answer (score 1):

You do not know how $dV$ looks like for a specific case. So, you have to use the general form of $dV$ which is what you have written.

You need to show that if you perform a coordinate transformation on the wedge products and on the determinant of the metric at the same time, everything will be cancelled and you will recover $dV$ again.